# ERROR ITMS-90363 "Invalid Info.plist key. The key 'CFBundleIcons~iPad in bundle ... is invalid."

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, submission

Archive submission failed due to the issues listed below: ERROR ITMS-90363 "Invalid Info.plist key. The key 'CFBundleIcons~iPad in bundle ... is invalid."

I am trying to submit the app to Apple. I added Watchkit extension. I keep getting this error.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

For the main app, I didn't include the iPad icons in the asset catalog.
[image]

Comment: I don't know exactly how i fixed to be honest. But for sure i still have iPad pictures